# Why doesn't the title tooltip work for floated elements?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a floated element, the whole purpose of which is to display an 'x' signifying that you can remove something:

```
.remove_button{
background-color:#ff3300;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Courier New,sans-serif;
font-weight:900;
font-size:20px;
float:right;
border-radius:5px;
padding:0px 6px 0px 6px;
margin-right:15px;
}

<div class="remove_button" title="Remove">x</div>
```

It does display a neat little 'x' over a red background (no need to make a picture, I'm bad at that), but the problem is that when the mouse hovers over the button the title attribute shows up inside the button, and as a tooltip too:

```
------xRemove------   one '-' is one pixel of padding
```

Comment: please provide image what you want to get output

Comment: You know the title tooltip trick.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of the title attribute. You may want to use the alt attribute instead, if you don't want the tooltip behavior. (Title is not necessary for accessibility issues, if that's your concern.)

Comment: I want the tooltip behavior, what I don't want is the text "Remove" inserted inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
.remove_button{
background-color:#ff3300;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Courier New,sans-serif;
font-weight:900;
font-size:20px;
float:right;
border-radius:5px;
padding:0px 6px 0px 6px;
margin-right:15px;
position:relative;
}
```

​    .tip{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #aab;
    background:#eef;
    padding:0 3px;
    left:15px;
    top:25px;
    }

```
.remove_button:hover .tip{
display:block;
}
```

​​​​​​​​​

Comment: add this HTML  <div class="remove_button">x<div class="tip">Remove</div></div>​​​​​​​​